# High CPU usage when reading from console

Tags: java, blocking

So i am writing a little program that takes user input

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String something = input.readLine();
    }
}
```

Here is the relavent section cut out, I run this and the main thread blocks on readline() but my CPU usage is ~15-20% consistently.

What is up here, is there a more efficient way to read from the console.

EDIT: I am on Mac OS 10.8 and the process has been running for 20 minutes now. The input.readline() statement is wrapped in a while true loop with some simple processing inside but i know the code is not getting there.

Comment: How much time does it last? Perhaps it is just the JVM that is finishing the startup...

Comment: It could be that your OS limiting resources on your program so you only get a max of 15-20%

Comment: I think providing your exact input would be useful.

Comment: Just tested it. Everything is ok. Maybe you have some background process running.

Comment: What OS is that? You don't tell...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have some kind of code that checks the status of readLine(), otherwise Java will continue to block.

```
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // handle contents of line here
}
```

You may be better off using the Scanner class to read user input.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = sc.nextInt();
....
```

Comment: yeah sorry, its exactly as you've suspected, I didnt expect that to be a problem, surely that isnt what is causing the CPU usage?

Comment: I've just tried using a scanner and it is still around 15% usage

Comment: I'm not sure about the CPU usage, but I would venture to guess that if the JVM is waiting for a read from the BufferedReader it might take up some resources during its checking process.